# minimize with orthogonal constraint

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, calculus-of-variations

Let $\mathcal{L}=(L^2(\mathbb{R}^3))^N$ be the product space with the associated norm
$$
\Vert U\Vert_0=\left(\sum^N_{i=1}\Vert u_i\Vert_0^2\right)^{1/2}
$$
where $U=(u_1,u_2,...,u_N)\in\mathcal{L}$. Let
$$
\mathcal{K}=\{U\in\mathcal{L};\int_{\mathbb{R}^3}u_iu_j=\delta_{i,j},\forall 1\leq i,j\leq N\}
$$
and  for any matrix $A\in\mathbb{R}^{N\times N}$ denote 
$$
AU=(...,\sum_{j=1}^N A_{ij}U_j,...,)^T
$$
For any $U_1,U_2\in\mathcal{K}$, is the following minimization problem have a unique solution
$$
\min\limits_{O\in\mathcal{O}^{N\times N}}\Vert OU_1-U_2\Vert_0
$$
where $\mathcal{O}^{N\times N}$ is the set of all unitary matrix.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Certainly not, as posed. Imagine the case when the whole set $U_1\cup U_2$ is orthonormal. Then the norm to minimize does not depend on $O$ at all.

Comment: @fedja oh. I see. Thank you very much.   I did not think about that.